# JavaFX and Lucene

Tags: java, javafx, lucene

I am creating a search engine kind of project where i have to make a UI in JavaFX and use Apache Lucene for the queries. I am in a stage where the UI in JavaFX works perfectly on its own(without calling any Lucene methods) and the queries for the Lucene also work fine on its own(in a separate java project). When I try to combine the two by creating an Object of Lucene into the action performed when I press the ENTER button it crashes hard and the exception is far from confusing.

I am providing the code for both my `Window` and my `LuceneTester` classes and the exception thrown.

Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        new Window(primaryStage);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Window class

```
public class Window{

    public Window(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(setSearch(), setBody());
        
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("The Reuters Search Assistant");
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("icon.png")));
        primaryStage.requestFocus();
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(1280);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(720);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    private VBox setSearch() {
        Label search = new Label("Search");
        search.setFont(new Font("arial", 30));
        search.setPadding(new Insets(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0));
        search.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        search.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
        
        TextField searchBar = new TextField();
        searchBar.setFont(new Font("arial", 14));
        searchBar.setPromptText("type here");
        searchBar.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        searchBar.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                searchAction(searchBar.getText());
            }
        });
        
        Separator separator = new Separator();
        separator.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
        separator.setPadding(new Insets(5.0, 0, 0, 0));
        
        VBox searchPanel = new VBox();
        searchPanel.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        searchPanel.setPadding(new Insets(5.0, 5.0, 0 ,5.0));
        searchPanel.setSpacing(5.0);
        searchPanel.fillWidthProperty();
        searchPanel.getChildren().addAll(search, searchBar, separator);
        return searchPanel;
    }
    
    private HBox setBody() {
        Button addBtn = new Button("Add Article");
        addBtn.setFont(new Font("arial", 20));
        addBtn.setMinWidth(170);
        addBtn.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            addArticleAction();
        });
        
        Button editBtn = new Button("Edit Article");
        editBtn.setFont(new Font("arial", 20));
        editBtn.setMinWidth(170);
        editBtn.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            editArticleAction();
        });
        
        Button delBtn = new Button("Delete Article");
        delBtn.setFont(new Font("arial", 20));
        delBtn.setMinWidth(170);
        delBtn.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            delArticleAction();
        });
        
        VBox buttonsBox = new VBox();
        buttonsBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        buttonsBox.setMinWidth(200);
        buttonsBox.setPadding(new Insets(15.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0));
        buttonsBox.setSpacing(20.0);
        buttonsBox.getChildren().addAll(addBtn, editBtn, delBtn);
        
        Separator separator = new Separator();
        separator.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        
        ListView listView = new ListView();
        listView.setMinWidth(1050);
        listView.setMinHeight(574);
        
        VBox listViewBox = new VBox();
        listViewBox.setPadding(new Insets(5.0, 0, 0, 1.0));
        listViewBox.getChildren().add(listView);
        
        HBox bodyPanel = new HBox();
        bodyPanel.getChildren().addAll(buttonsBox, separator, listViewBox);
        return bodyPanel;
    }
    
    private void searchAction(String searchString) {
        System.out.println("Searching for : " + searchString);
        // Here is where the exception occurs.
        LuceneTester search = new LuceneTester(searchString);
    }
    
    private void addArticleAction() {
        System.out.println("add article");
    }
    
    private void editArticleAction() {
        System.out.println("edit article");
    }
    
    private void delArticleAction() {
        System.out.println("delete article");
    }
}
```

LuceneTester class

```
public class LuceneTester {
    
    String indexDir = "C:\\Users\\stefa\\eclipse-workspace\\TReSA\\index";
    String dataDir = "C:\\Users\\stefa\\eclipse-workspace\\TReSA\\data";
    Indexer indexer;
    Searcher searcher;
    
    public LuceneTester(String searchString) {
        try {
            this.createIndex();
            this.search(searchString);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private void createIndex() throws IOException {
        indexer = new Indexer(indexDir);
        int numIndexed;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        numIndexed = indexer.createIndex(dataDir, new TextFileFilter());
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        indexer.close();
        System.out.println(numIndexed + " File(s) indexed, time taken: " + (endTime-startTime) + " ms");
    }
    
    private void search(String searchQuery) throws IOException, ParseException {
        searcher = new Searcher(indexDir);
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        TopDocs hits = searcher.search(searchQuery);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(hits.totalHits +" found. Time : " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms");
        for(ScoreDoc scoreDoc : hits.scoreDocs) {
            Document doc = searcher.getDocument(scoreDoc);
            System.out.println("File: " + doc.get(LuceneConstants.FILE_PATH));
        }
    }
}
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/ParseException
    at com.TReSA.main.Window.searchAction(Window.java:116)
    at com.TReSA.main.Window.lambda$0(Window.java:52)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:4105)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2156)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2630)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:150)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$1(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:249)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:548)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:972)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 29 more
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException` means that there is a missing Dependency from Lucene, so you should check your build-tools setup.

But it also means that an Exception occurred so you might want to doublecheck if the Lucene only Code really works.

Comment: I checked my code again and it seems to work fine.
In my Java build path i am including the lucene.core and lucene.queryparser libraries.
Do i have to include another one which supports JavaFX to work? And if yes, which one?

Comment: There's no specific JavaFX package that would be needed. At least, that's not what this error points to. You'd need to show how you're building and including these dependencies. FWIW you'd probably be better off switching to Maven or Gradle to manage your dependencies, since it sounds like you're trying to do it manually. It'll make your life much easier in the long run.

Comment: I just realized that my eclipse has disabled the libraries in the dependencies section. With a restart and after reinstalling them it worked perfectly fine. Thanks a lot!